# Python grouping of columns

Tags: python, bigdata

working on some machine learning and need to perform some data exploration

```
print(df.groupby('model_new')['MFG'])
```

gives me:

current output:

```
**MFG        model_new**   Count
HGST         model1          2
HGST         model2          434
HGST         model3          3
Toshiba      model1          12
Toshiba      model2          3

expected output
    MFG      model_count
    HGST           3
    Toshiba        2
```

.....

Comment: The current line of code would return a groupby object, as there's no aggregation applied to the groups. Looks like your problem is that you should be grouping by `MFG`, not `model_new`

Comment: I think you need `print(df.groupby(['MFG','model_new']).size())`

Comment: Please add the head of the original data frame

Comment: Hi thanks. i tries that but doesnt give me the right answer.

Comment: @Yusufsn thanks i tried that but stil get the same answer

Comment: Maybe you need [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). But please show us your expected output. Also your dataframe snippet.

Comment: @Yusufsn showing in the questin now

Comment: `df.groupby('MFG').count()` ?

Comment: `df.groupby('MFG')["model_new"].nunique()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should answer your problem :

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('MFG')['model_new'].count())
```

and if you want unique values :

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('MFG')['model_new'].nunique())
```

In your case they both give the same result but with other DataFrame it could change.

Comment: thank you! this is the answer. the second one with nunique